# Comma operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Following [this](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs) tutorial, what do these lines mean?

```
var join = require('path').join
  , pfx = join(__dirname, '../_certs/pfx.p12');
```

The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

How could these lines easier be written?

Comment: That **is** a comma, but it is **not** the "comma operator".

Comment: @Pointy - That's actually right, it's just a seperator in this case.

Comment: References on Pointy's comment: [grammar of a `var` statement using the comma (not the comma operator)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement) and [the comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-comma-operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the comma separates two variables, and that's it, it's the same as writing

```
var join = require('path').join;
var pfx  = join(__dirname, '../_certs/pfx.p12');
```

Instead one can do

```
var join = require('path').join,
    pfx  = join(__dirname, '../_certs/pfx.p12');
```

In this case, the comma is just a seperator, much as it would be an object literal or array.

The comma **operator**, which is only an operator when it acts on two expressions, one on the left side, and one on the right side,  can be used when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression.

One example would be in a return statement

```
[1,2,3].reduce(function(a,b,i) {
    return a[i] = b, a; // returns a;
},[]);
```

etc...

Comment: yep it's shorthand so you don't have to write var twice when declaring variables in succession

Comment: Shorthand, yes; but this notation doesn't make for clean git diffs when adding or deleting variables at the beginning or end. For that reason, I dislike it.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially the same as a semi-colon in many cases, so you could rewrite it as this:

```
var join = require('path').join;
var pfx = join(__dirname, '../_certs/pfx.p12');
```

The difference comes down to lines like declaring variables (like your example), in which the `var` is applied to each element in the comma-separated list. Beyond that, it's more or less a semi-colon, though it's not recommended to use the comma syntax in most cases.

I personally prefer it for the variables, because I think this look a little cleaner:

```
var a = 5,
    b = 6,
    c, 
    d;
```

But others dislike it.